# Extracting data-href from li tag

Tags: php, laravel, domparser

I' am trying to extract URL of `data-href` but, facing some trouble. it doesn't have a tag. so I don't know how to get data-href Attribute. The website is here:`https://www.proud-web.jp/search/kansai/area/osaka/`

Here is the data I want:

```
<div class="box-search-result">
            <form action="/module/material/SiryoOrderTop.xphp" method="GET" name="favoritebox" target="_blank">
                    <ul class="list-search-result">
                        <li class="list-search-result-item" data-href="https://www.proud-web.jp/kansai/mansion/shimizudani/"
```

Here is my codes:

```
$url = 'https://www.proud- web.jp/search/kansai/area/osaka/';
$parser = getSiteContent($url);

$link = [];
$allDivs = [];
$allDivs = $parser->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach ($allDivs as $div) {
      if ($div->getAttribute('class') == 'box-search-result') {
          $linkRef = $div->getAttribute('data-href');
          var_dump($linkRef);

   }
}
```

How can I take the `data-href`'s URL? Any idea? Thank you!
I am using DOMparser by the way.

Comment: you want to grab the `li` element from within each `div` then get the `data-href` attribute. You're just trying to grab it from the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to grab the `li` element from within each `div` then get the `data-href` attribute. You're just trying to grab it from the div

```
$allDivs = $parser->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach ($allDivs as $div) {
      if ($div->getAttribute('class') == 'box-search-result') {
          $allLi = $div->getElementsByTagName('li');
          foreach ($allLi as $li){
          $linkRef = $li->getAttribute('data-href');
          var_dump($linkRef);
          }

   }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure on the syntax here for domParser but the issue is the same with you grabbing the `div` and not the `li`. You may have to loop through the `childNodes` property of your `$div` variables and check if the `nodeName` is a `ul` and then loop through the `childNodes` property of those looking for `li` as the `nodeName` e.g

```
$allDivs = $parser->getElementsByTagName('div');
        foreach ($allDivs as $div) {
          if ($div->getAttribute('class') == 'box-search-result') {
              foreach($div->childNodes as $node) {
                   if($node->nodeName == 'ul') {
                        foreach($node->childNodes as $liNode) {
                             if ($liNode->nodeName == 'li') {
                                 $linkRef = $liNode->getAttribute('data-href');
                                 var_dump($linkRef);
                             }
                        }
                   }
              }

       }
    }
```